# Regular Expression in android for password without spaces

Tags: java, android

I have a EditText field in android. The password should contain minimum 4 characters and maximum 20 characters without spaces at the start or in the middle. Example blankspaceRaghu and RaghublankspaceRaghu should not be alllowed.

```
Pass= password.getText().toString();    

Pattern p= Pattern.compile("[^\\S]+[a-z,A-Z]+");

Matcher m = p.matcher(Pass);
```

Comment: Post what you have done so far (or) at least example input and output.

Comment: Are you saying that spaces *are* allowed at the *end*?

Comment: yes. user can have a password length between 4 and 20. Password should not have spaces at the start or middle.

Comment: Updated my answer, now should match your requirements

Comment: why is this downvoted. Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated - Spaces are allowed at the end....

```
Pass= password.getText().toString();    
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("((?!\\s)\\A)(\\s|(?<!\\s)\\S){4,20}\\Z");
Matcher m = p.matcher(Pass);
```

This matches

- Match start of string as long as it is not followed by a space
- Match 4 to 20 occurrences of either a space or a non space provided it is not prefixed by a space
- Match end of string

Comment: Scratch that, miss read that as spaces at beginning or end were not allowed but spaces in middle were, will edit

Comment: Thanks Bob. I am giving ur regex a try.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pass= mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,20}$"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(Pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
"\\A\\w{4,20}\\z"
```

`\\A` stands for "beginning of the input".

`\\w` is any alphanumeric (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) character. When you don't allow digits, replace it with `[a-zA-Z]`

`{4,20}` means the previous things between 4 and 20 times in a row.

`\\z` is the end of the string. You didn't mentioned if you allow spaces AFTER the password string. When you want to allow this, insert `\\s*` (nothing or any number of whitespaces) before `\\z`.

More about regular expression syntax can be found in the documentation of [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to match with a RegEx of `\\A\\S{4,20}\\Z`. That's any non-whitespace characters, with a length between 4 and 20, matching the whole string.

Comment: this doesn't fulfill the requirement of having no spaces in front of the password

Comment: You need the `^` and `$` around the regex to match the exact string

Comment: be careful: `^` and `$` match the beginning of a line. So when there are linebreaks in the string (\n), ^ and $ will also react on them.

Comment: @Philipp - Ah, yes make sure you use [DOITALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode or `\\A` and `\\Z`

Answer (score 0):

You could try negative matching - that way you don't have to fuss around with negated character classes.

Match the password against `/\s/`. If it matches, you have spaces somewhere in it and it should be rejected. If not, you're free to go.

Comment: However that still doesn't match 4 - 20 chars